# Really Need Advice Regarding Broken Links - Support team tells me it's fine

Tags: javascript, html

I just re-did a site, when I check it for broken links (using brokenlinkcheck), it comes up with 73 broken links that are all like this: www.example.com/site/numbers are here/${href}. Support over there tells me that (this quote is from one rep who got 'news' from another):

**QUOTE:** "did not find an issue. They had mentioned that the examples I showed were referring to  tags with an attribute data-href that have the broken url. There type of links are not clickable and can not be visited and are mistakenly recognized by the tool as broken links.  The link checker mistakenly alerts for 'data-href=...' (its not an href attribute)." **END QUOTE**

BUT,  seeing the link in my email to them, I CAN click on it (why are they saying it's not clickable???). **My main question is:** will Google see this as broken links? Support is telling me there's no issue. But it looks like an issue to me. I cannot go in and fix myself, I would need specific wording to try and convince support to fix it. So, if you DO believe it is a problem, could you suggest how I word that in an email to support, who seems to think it is fine?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: There are no technical details provided in the question. There is no a single official and well known definition for the "broken link" term so you have to explain to us what you exactly mean.

Answer (score 1):

Without a URL to check it, or a sample of the html code, it is hard to say for sure. What the rep said does make sense, it is possible for the broken addresses to only be present in a `data-` attribute and therefor not to be clickable, Google would also not take these URLs into account while crawling the site.

Yes if you take the URL out of the `data-` attribute and paste it into an email it will be clickable but not clickable on your site. Again without a link to the site hard to say for sure.

Can you by clicking around your site get to and click the broken link? If not then it may just be a problem of the tool you are using.

Comment: Welcome to the world of parsing HTML (a non-regular language) with regular expressions. A lot of tools do a quick and dirty job of processing HTML with out parsing it properly. Often the attitude is _if it starts with http it must be a link_ .

Comment: Yep, for a second I forgot that in this world people don't know how to deal with html, hence dropped my comment and about to switch back to my ideal world again :-)

Comment: I apologize in advance for not understanding all the edits I was told to make to my question. These links are not anywhere in my actual site. They are 'appearing' in the broken link checker tool. I thought that Google used a similar 'tool' to crawl sites, and if so, would they ignore these 'fake' pages? When you say it may be a problem with the tool I'm using, I'm not sure that is it because I made 7 sites before this, all the same template and the tool did not find this issue. You guys are all much smarter than me, so again I'm sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology.